# Web Analytics and category tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics

I am new to Marketing Cloud and trying to gather more information on the `Web Analytics` capabilities.

I have implemented the Collect code on my testing site and I can see data coming through strait away which is great. I added more code to track a category (as per the documentation https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/collect_code/install_collect_code/track_page_view/#TrackCategory)

I believe this is working, but I have no idea about how to see this data in the dashboard or action it...

My code is very simple:
_etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "category" : "News" }]);

But I cannot find any references or documentation around how to use this data.

Sorry if this is a simple one, but any help here is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue here. I couldn't find any advanced documentation like we have on Google analytics.

Did you manage finding how to action an event from Web Analytics ?

Comment: Actually no, I didnt, the SF team got back to me and essentially concluded that this service was not available and that I should use the Predictive Intelligence package instead :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Saleswings, we can integrate with Salesforce Marketing Cloud to add website lead tracking, lead activity scoring and add a sort of "lead deck" for inside sales teams.